# which is give best performance storyboard or .Xib file?

Tags: ios, objective-c

i am doing one simple apps project and using storyboards. but i am confuse to use either storyboard or xib file in my project ?
which of the best as performance base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for you last comment : 
you can use following code for designing UIButton dynamically-

```
int yPosition = 0;    
for (int i = 0; i<10; i++){        
 UIButton *aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]; 
[aButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];     
[aButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Button %d",index] forState:UIControlStateNormal];    
[aButton setFrame:CGRectMake(20, yPosition, 100, 50)];    
[aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(aButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];    
[aView addSubview:aButton];    
yPosition += 50;
}

- (IBAction)aButtonClicked:(id)sender
{    
NSLog(@"Clicked on button with title %@",[sender titleLabel].text);
}
```

Comment: thanks for that ...........yes i implement this code in my project but i want each button text  diffrent  like angrysms, aniversary sms ,birthday sms etc on each button.  what can i do.

Comment: and i want one search bar option top my window to search these button. please anybody know this answer reply.

Comment: i implement dynamic button code but button display vertically i want three row with horizontally in my screen what can i do for that ?? have any code for that

Answer (score 1):

There is no performance improvements in Storyboard versus Xib files, they both are modified XML files. However storyboards are meant to be easier to use and give better overall look of your app. My personal experience is that storyboards are OK for really small apps(let's say 3-4 screens at top), however if you have complex app with 10-15 screen storyboards becomes a nightmare to maintain.

UPDATE

Also what I don't like about storyboards, is that if I wan't to reuse some screen in other application, I'll have to copy .m and .h files, and then search through storyboard to find my related interface file and put it inside new storyboard. Without them I'll just copy paste h,m,xib files(which I usually put in separate folder) for each screen at new project and use them.

Comment: i have 8 screen i my apps so can use storyboard?

Comment: Well this isn't really a yes/no question. You can use storyboard even when you have 100 screens, however in my point of view it's horrible to understand what is happening and which goes where. For your scenario I'll go for storyboard, but only if I know there won't be future screens for some new features.

Comment: I've edited my original answer with one more thing to keep in mind, please have a look

Comment: i am newly enter in iOs. can u help me ? how to create 10 button dynamically in one screen using storyboard? please help ??

Comment: btw you can use multiple sotryboards in one project as well

Comment: i go with storyboard  thanks for give me your valuable suggestion

Comment: i use one storyboard only with different uiviewcontroller   and i want to design 10 buttons dynamically in one window with search bar   can you help me ? i know how to create search bar but button don't no.

Comment: i want add uisearch bar dynamically in my apps  i without using table view ...???